# as.mids in r package mice yields "Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length"

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

R kept crashing when I attempted to use mice with my dataset so I did my mi in SPSS v. 24. I then imported the multiply imputed data into R as Imp5N2NPV4_2_17.

I want to convert that dataframe into mids to proceed with my analyses, but am getting an error for which I cannot find help.

Here is a glimpse of the dataframe:

```
> head(Imp5N2NPV4_2_17)
# A tibble: 6 × 137
  Imputation_    ID  Site Subject  DateSOPS     DateNP     DaysNPfromSOPS Visit TypeConvNon  TypeCtPr  TypeName
    <dbl+lbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <date>     <date>               <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>     <chr>
1           0  1001     1       1  2009-03-09 2009-03-13              4     1           0         1 Prodromal
2           0  1001     1       1  2009-03-09       <NA>            NaN     2           0         1 Prodromal
3           0  1001     1       1  2009-03-09       <NA>            NaN     3           0         1 Prodromal
4           0  1001     1       1  2009-03-09       <NA>            NaN     4           0         1 Prodromal
5           0  1002     1       2  2009-01-05 2009-04-17            102     1           0         1 Prodromal
6           0  1002     1       2  2009-01-05       <NA>            NaN     2           0         1 Prodromal
# ... with 125 more variables: Type3gp <dbl+lbl>, CHR_converter <dbl+lbl>, Age.SOPS <dbl>, age_ym <dbl>, sex <dbl>,
```

Here is the code:

`Imp5N2NPV4_2_17<-as.mids(Imp5N2NPV4_2_17,.imp = 1, .id = 2)`

This is the error I do not understand:

> Error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = value) : 
>         invalid 'row.names' length

Thank you for any help

Comment: try converting your data to a data,frame ie not a tibble . ps did you use the function mice before using as.mids

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. I had written a response but somehow I guess I did not complete the upload of it. I did convert it to a data.frame and this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: okay, can you edit your question with example code that reproduces this , say using the nhanes dataset?